# how to fetch the mpeg stream from local URL/ COM port using shell commands in unix based(raspberry) system?

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi, shell-script, video-streaming, mpeg

I am looking for a suggestion through which I can try fetching some mpeg stream at very low frame rates from the local IP/COM port and transport it whole into other system with the help of an application(i have that application ready to transport the results from into other system).
But the question is how?

My other question is even if i am able to send the video stream data ,do i need to decode it again such as to display later into any media streaming software?

Comment: By "fetching at low frame rates", what do you mean? Does the input stream have a low frame rate, or do you want to drop some frames while reading it? Also, do you know how to access the raw data from the port itself, and what specific protocol is used to transmit the video? ("some mpeg stream" is a little vague. The stream can be raw MPEG-TS, it can be wrapped in RTP, etc.)

Comment: by low frame rate, i mean the input would be in low frame rates.not sure about the raw data thing.but yes i might go for webrtc  maybe, as  my original  intent is to show  the video feed into a canvas element of an html webpage .